# Angular 6 Dependency Injection factory services are not being singleton

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, factory-pattern

I have two modules AppModule and lazyLoadModule. where I am lazy loading lazyLoadModule from Appmodule. I want to share my providers with lazy loaded module [refer](https://medium.com/@chrishouse/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7). I have created a SharedProviderModule as follows and imported in AppModule using SharedProviderModule.forRoot():

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, ModuleWithProviders  } from '@angular/core';
import { CounterService } from './counter.service';
@NgModule({
})
export class SharedProviderModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedProviderModule ,
      providers: [ CounterService 
      {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: appConfigFactory,
        deps: [CounterService],
        multi: true
      },
]
    }
  }
}
```

As per the reference blog providers should have single instance for both modules, but right now for lazy loaded module new instance of provider is getting initiated. I am overriding some value using factory provider in  SharedProviderModule which are not reflected in lazy loaded module. Is it something I forgot to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your lazy loaded module will automatically have access to all providers registered in the app. When your lazy loaded module imports a module with `forRoot` it actually registers those providers AGAIN, causing your issue.

You should never have a shared module containing providers, unless you don't want them to be singletons. If both your `AppModule` and lazy loaded module require a provider then register or import it in your `AppModule` and it will be available everywhere.